# Prestashop 1.6.1.11 If user not logged show (This.)

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Currently trying to dig my way around Prestashop, 1.6.1.11. I understand it a little bit but I wouldn't say I'm experienced.

I'm after a way to check if the user is logged in, which I have found examples for this elsewhere using .tpl files. However I need to action a response if the user is not logged in The thread I found is the reverse of which.

> e.g. If user is not logged show element.

I found this line `{if $logged} ..... {/if}` , on the prestashop forums, but the thread is rather old and I'm not sure if this holds up as it dates back to version 1.5. I may be showing my inexperience here, but you don't know until you ask.

As a bit of background as to what it is specifically that I'm trying to achieve is to display a full width / height image with a sign-in element layered over top within the center.

I want to essentially give the user only one element to interact with and use to sign in.

I hope I have explained myself well enough, any help is appreciated. I'll keep looking and if I find anything useful I'll post it here.

**Edit**

[Link to Prestashop thread.](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/300678-smarty-check-if-user-is-logged-in/)

[My Own Prestashop question.](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/595108-16111-check-if-user-is-logged/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some digging, I was able to use the following to get the function I desired.

```html
<!-- Check Login -->
<div id="check-log">
  {if $is_logged}

    <a href=".." id="Logout" />Logout</a>

  {else}

    <a href=".." id="Login" />Login</a>

  {/if}
</div>
```

This code should be placed within the `header.tpl` Theme file.

---

This variable is defined in class `/classes/controller/FrontController.php` in method `init()`:

```php
$this->context->smarty->assign(array(
    // Useful for layout.tpl
    'mobile_device'       => $this->context->getMobileDevice(),
    'link'                => $link,
    'cart'                => $cart,
    'currency'            => $currency,
    'currencyRate'        => (float)$currency->getConversationRate(),
    'cookie'              => $this->context->cookie,
    'page_name'           => $page_name,
    'hide_left_column'    => !$this->display_column_left,
    'hide_right_column'   => !$this->display_column_right,
    'base_dir'            => _PS_BASE_URL_.__PS_BASE_URI__,
    'base_dir_ssl'        => $protocol_link.Tools::getShopDomainSsl().__PS_BASE_URI__,
    'force_ssl'           => Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED') && Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED_EVERYWHERE'),
    'content_dir'         => $protocol_content.Tools::getHttpHost().__PS_BASE_URI__,
    'base_uri'            => $protocol_content.Tools::getHttpHost().__PS_BASE_URI__.(!Configuration::get('PS_REWRITING_SETTINGS') ? 'index.php' : ''),
    'tpl_dir'             => _PS_THEME_DIR_,
    'tpl_uri'             => _THEME_DIR_,
    'modules_dir'         => _MODULE_DIR_,
    'mail_dir'            => _MAIL_DIR_,
    'lang_iso'            => $this->context->language->iso_code,
    'lang_id'             => (int)$this->context->language->id,
    'language_code'       => $this->context->language->language_code ? $this->context->language->language_code : $this->context->language->iso_code,
    'come_from'           => Tools::getHttpHost(true, true).Tools::htmlentitiesUTF8(str_replace(array('\'', '\\'), '', urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))),
    'cart_qties'          => (int)$cart->nbProducts(),
    'currencies'          => Currency::getCurrencies(),
    'languages'           => $languages,
    'meta_language'       => implode(',', $meta_language),
    'priceDisplay'        => Product::getTaxCalculationMethod((int)$this->context->cookie->id_customer),
    'is_logged'           => (bool)$this->context->customer->isLogged(),
    'is_guest'            => (bool)$this->context->customer->isGuest(),
    'add_prod_display'    => (int)Configuration::get('PS_ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY_DISPLAY'),
    'shop_name'           => Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_NAME'),
    'roundMode'           => (int)Configuration::get('PS_PRICE_ROUND_MODE'),
    'use_taxes'           => (int)Configuration::get('PS_TAX'),
    'show_taxes'          => (int)(Configuration::get('PS_TAX_DISPLAY') == 1 && (int)Configuration::get('PS_TAX')),
    'display_tax_label'   => (bool)$display_tax_label,
    'vat_management'      => (int)Configuration::get('VATNUMBER_MANAGEMENT'),
    'opc'                 => (bool)Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_PROCESS_TYPE'),
    'PS_CATALOG_MODE'     => (bool)Configuration::get('PS_CATALOG_MODE') || (Group::isFeatureActive() && !(bool)Group::getCurrent()->show_prices),
    'b2b_enable'          => (bool)Configuration::get('PS_B2B_ENABLE'),
    'request'             => $link->getPaginationLink(false, false, false, true),
    'PS_STOCK_MANAGEMENT' => Configuration::get('PS_STOCK_MANAGEMENT'),
    'quick_view'          => (bool)Configuration::get('PS_QUICK_VIEW'),
    'shop_phone'          => Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_PHONE'),
    'compared_products'   => is_array($compared_products) ? $compared_products : array(),
    'comparator_max_item' => (int)Configuration::get('PS_COMPARATOR_MAX_ITEM'),
    'currencySign'        => $currency->sign, // backward compat, see global.tpl
    'currencyFormat'      => $currency->format, // backward compat
    'currencyBlank'       => $currency->blank, // backward compat
));

// Deprecated
$this->context->smarty->assign(array(
    'id_currency_cookie' => (int)$currency->id,
    'logged'             => $this->context->customer->isLogged(),
    'customerName'       => ($this->context->customer->logged ? $this->context->cookie->customer_firstname.' '.$this->context->cookie->customer_lastname : false)
));
```

Comment: I've edited your question to add more informations. But the variable used in your template should be `$is_logged` and not `$logged`.

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre Thanks for the assist, I did try to find this file to refrence it earlier in my search but I come up short when locating it. Thanks again it's valuable learning material.

Comment: On a side note however, `$logged` appears to be completely functional and non-problematic. Could you help my understand why?

Comment: I've edited your answer again to add the related `logged` variable declaration. It is just under the previous line in the same file. As noted in the comment this variable is deprecated and is only declared for retrocompatibility with older themes.